# How to add only one product using Magento 2 REST API?

Tags: magento2, product, cart, addtocart, rest-api

I am using REST API for Magento 2.

I want to add 1 product only in Cart using REST API. Like if cart is empty one product is added is cart and if one product is in cart then remove that existing product and add new product in cart.

Thanks, Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I have Follow this article https://magecomp.com/blog/programmatically-clear-shopping-cart-magento-2/ to solve the issue.